# Problem using the TRANSPOSE() function

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help with a Google Sheets.  Let's say I've got a column and in the column I have three rows containing the values A, B, and C:

```
Column:
A
B
C
```

I need to transpose the column so that it reads horizontally:

```
Columns:
A     B     C
```

In an empty cell, I can use the function `=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)` to get the rows switched into columns.  My problem is that the three columns are a reference to the original column, and I can't erase the original column or it will mess up these three new columns.  I also can't paste the new columns into a new spreadsheet.

How can I "unlink" the three new columns from the original column?

Answer (score 3):

In new Google Sheets there is no need for a function. Just select `B` and `C`, Ctrl+c, select the cell immediately to the right of `A`and Edit, Paste special, Paste **transpose**.

This creates copies of `B` and `C` but there is no linkage so those *below* `A` may be deleted without affect those *to the right of* `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Select the three columns, copy them and then paste them in a new row, pasting **values only**. Then you can erase the original column.

[image]

[image]

[image]